# How can I stop, or extend the browser timeout while in a breakpoint for Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, vaadin

When debugging a Selenium test I'll set a breakpoint, and usually run off to look at the DOM, and test xpaths. The problem is the browser times out after 90 seconds and goes away. How can I extend or disable this browser timeout so it stays open for long enough for me to do actual work in it?

I'm using the Java version of the API.

I do not want the browser to close simply because I'm sitting on a breakpoint and no commands are being sent to it.

**update**

we are using `vaadin-testbench-standalone-4.0.3.jar` hub/node scripts to run? selenium. Given comments I think this may be what's killing the browser. I see the `hub` output emitting this

```
13:58:02.152 INFO - Session 97ae07ab-ca71-4aa9-a2b1-9a75859f6c9b deleted due to client timeout
```

Comment: "the browser times out after 20 seconds and goes away..."  This doesn't happen unless [`WebDriver#quit()`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.java#L136) is called, or some other external process is closing it.  you should make sure that some other process isn't closing this.  maybe a cleanup script somewhere?

Comment: @sircapsalot I think you're on to something, updated the information.